# How to get ttl value in pyping python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below program only print if the server is up or down using `pyping`, but I need to print the output with TTL (time to live) value.

```
import pyping
servers = (
  '192.168.1.1',
  '192.168.1.2',
  '192.168.1.3'
)

temp = []

for server in servers:
    checker = pyping.ping(server)
    if checker.ret_code == 0:
        body = "%s Server is UP" % (server)
        temp.append(body)
    else:
        body = "%s Server is Down" % (server)
        temp.append(body)

print(temp)
```

Guys if you have any other ideas to get ttl value kindly post it..

Answer (score 0):

use Popen from [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

you can use `returncode` of command success `if >0` then not success

```
import subprocess
import re
p = subprocess.Popen(["ping","www.google.com"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=p.communicate()[0]
if p.returncode > 0:
    print('server error')
else:
    pattern = re.compile('TTL=\d*')
    print(pattern.search(str(res)).group())
```

## OUT

```
TTL=56
```

on linux pass the one more `-c` along with command to avoid endless ping

Comment: can you tell me the regex code to do that because i'm new to python

Comment: thank you :) i want to figure out how to print server is up or down with subprocess its easy with pyping but dont know how to get that output with subprocess and regex